# Control not allowing selection when textbox is populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using calendar extender to create a popup textbox when a user click in a specific textboxk:

```
<asp:Label ID="searchDateFromLabel" runat="server" Text="From:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="searchDateFrom"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="fromCalendarExtender" TargetControlID="searchDateFrom" runat="server">    
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>

<asp:Label ID="searchDateToLabel" runat="server" Text="To:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="searchDateTo"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="toCalendarExtender" TargetControlID="searchDateTo" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

[image]

Additionally, I populate the textboxes with default dates on page load:

```
fromCalendarExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
toCalendarExtender.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

The issue I am having is that when a user clicks a textbox that is populated, it won't let them choose another date (other than the one the texbox was populated with) unless they first delete the text currently in the box.

How do I allow them to select any date?

Answer (score 2):

Set `PopupControlID` to the TextBox you are trying use to select the date.  It should then force the data-selector to pop up whenever the user gives focus to the TextBox.

Comment: PopupControlId is not a property for ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender: Parser Error Message: Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not have a public property named 'PopupControlID'.

Comment: Sorry, `PopupButtonID`.  Are you programming in Notepad or something where you can't use Intellisense to look through a list of properties available to a Control?